# Join texts based on condition in an array of dictionaries in JS/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, dictionary

I have data like this:

```
Record= [
  { "tid": 1, "token_text": "Canis", "spanid": 1, "label": "Name" },
  { "tid": 2, "token_text": "Familiaris", "spanid": 1, "label": "Name" },
  { "tid": 3, "token_text": "is" },
  { "tid": 4, "token_text": "the" },
  { "tid": 5, "token_text": "scientific" },
  { "tid": 6, "token_text": "name" },
  { "tid": 7, "token_text": "of" },
  { "tid": 8, "token_text": "dog", "spanid": 2, "label": "species" },
  { "tid": 9, "token_text": "." }
]
```

I want to create another array of dictionaries like the data where the token_text strings that have the same spanid are joined and the tid and label_name can be the same as that of the first occurrence. I want to do this while keeping the order of the elements in the array the same as that of the Record array. I want to do this in JS/ React. I will appreciate any leads in this matter. The output will look like the following:

```
Record = [
  { "tid": 1, "token_text": "Canis Familiaris", "spanid": 1, "label": "Name" },
  { "tid": 3, "token_text": "is" },
  { "tid": 4, "token_text": "the" },
  { "tid": 5, "token_text": "scientific" },
  { "tid": 6, "token_text": "name" },
  { "tid": 7, "token_text": "of" },
  { "tid": 8, "token_text": "dog", "spanid": 2, "label": "species" },
  { "tid": 9, "token_text": "." }
]
```

I tried looping but couldn't figure out exactly.

```
for (let j = 0; j < spanid.length; j++) {
  var arr = [];
  Records.forEach(i => {
    if (i.spanid === spanid[j]) {
      arr.push(i.tid);
    }
  })
}
```

Is there a way to do it like this to join the token_texts with same spanids and delete the instances where that have duplicate spanids?

Answer (score 0):

```
const record = [
  { "tid": 1, "token_text": "Canis", "spanid": 1, "label": "Name" },
  { "tid": 2, "token_text": "Familiaris", "spanid": 1, "label": "Name" },
  { "tid": 3, "token_text": "is" },
  { "tid": 4, "token_text": "the" },
  { "tid": 5, "token_text": "scientific" },
  { "tid": 6, "token_text": "name" },
  { "tid": 7, "token_text": "of" },
  { "tid": 8, "token_text": "dog", "spanid": 2, "label": "species" },
  { "tid": 9, "token_text": "." }
];

const transformedRecord = [];
const spanidSet = new Set();

record.forEach(item => {
  if (item.spanid && !spanidSet.has(item.spanid)) {
    const joinedText = record
      .filter(i => i.spanid === item.spanid)
      .map(i => i.token_text)
      .join(' ');
      
    transformedRecord.push({
      tid: item.tid,
      token_text: joinedText,
      spanid: item.spanid,
      label: item.label
    });
    
    spanidSet.add(item.spanid);
  } else if (!item.spanid) {
    transformedRecord.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(transformedRecord);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array of tokens, and check the previous token's label against the current.

In order to append to the previous `token_text` you need to verify three things:

1. There is a previous (only false for the first iteration)
2. The current token has a `label`
3. The current and previous token labels match

#### Working example

**Note:** You could shorten the if-condition (below) to simply:

```js
if (token.label && token.label === prev?.label) {
```

```js
const record = [
  { "tid": 1, "token_text": "Canis", "spanid": 1, "label": "Name" },
  { "tid": 2, "token_text": "Familiaris", "spanid": 1, "label": "Name" },
  { "tid": 3, "token_text": "is" },
  { "tid": 4, "token_text": "the" },
  { "tid": 5, "token_text": "scientific" },
  { "tid": 6, "token_text": "name" },
  { "tid": 7, "token_text": "of" },
  { "tid": 8, "token_text": "dog", "spanid": 2, "label": "species" },
  { "tid": 9, "token_text": "." }
];

const joinTokensByLabel = (tokens) => {
  return tokens.reduce((result, token) => {
    const prev = result[result.length - 1];
    if (prev && token.label != null && token.label === prev.label) {
      prev.token_text += ` ${token.token_text}`;
    } else {
      result.push(structuredClone(token));
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
};

const fixed = joinTokensByLabel(record);

console.log(fixed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```